# Flutter Future<bool> vs bool type

Tags: flutter, future

My Flutter project has a utility.dart file and a main.dart file. I call the functions in the main.dart file but it has problems. It always showAlert "OK", i think the problem is the the utility class checkConnection() returns a future bool type.

main.dart:

```
if (Utility.checkConnection()==false) {
  Utility.showAlert(context, "internet needed");
} else {
  Utility.showAlert(context, "OK");
}
```

[image]

utility.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Utility {


  static Future<bool> checkConnection() async{

    ConnectivityResult connectivityResult = await (new Connectivity().checkConnectivity());

    debugPrint(connectivityResult.toString());

    if ((connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) || (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi)){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  static void showAlert(BuildContext context, String text) {
    var alert = new AlertDialog(
      content: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[Text(text)],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text(
              "OK",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
            ))
      ],
    );

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return alert;
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to get the `bool` out of `Future<bool>`. Use can `then block` or `await`.

with then block

```
_checkConnection() {
  Utiliy.checkConnection().then((connectionResult) {
    Utility.showAlert(context, connectionResult ? "OK": "internet needed");
  })
}
```

with await

```
_checkConnection() async {
 bool connectionResult = await Utiliy.checkConnection();
 Utility.showAlert(context, connectionResult ? "OK": "internet needed");
}
```

For more details, refer [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures).

Answer (score 23):

In Future functions you must return future results, so you need to change the return of:

```
return true;
```

To:

```
return Future<bool>.value(true);
```

So full function with correct return is:

```
 static Future<bool> checkConnection() async{

    ConnectivityResult connectivityResult = await (new Connectivity().checkConnectivity());

    debugPrint(connectivityResult.toString());

    if ((connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) || (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi)){
      return Future<bool>.value(true);
    } else {
      return Future<bool>.value(false);
    }
  }
```