# Flutter returning a bool type from a Future<bool> Method

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This question is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477468/flutter-futurebool-vs-bool-type) but the explanation didn't quite help for my use-case. I have a method of type Future that return a bool performing a query to cloud firestore to check if the username the user is entering already exists.

```
static Future<bool> doesNameAlreadyExist(String value, String 
name) async{
final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where(value, isEqualTo: name)
  .limit(1)
  .getDocuments();
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
 return  documents.length == 1;
```

}

When i call that method here i get this error [image]

Is there a way to get a return type of bool from a Future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type returned from `doesNameAlreadyExist` is `Future<bool>`,
so the line `doesNameAlreadyExist("userName", usernameController.value) == true`,
is actually `Future<bool> == bool`.
You need to await, or then the result.

```
doesNameAlreadyExist("userName", usernameController.value).then(value => value == true)
```

or

```
(await doesNameAlreadyExist("userName", usernameController.value)) == true
```

Read more about async programming here: [Dart Futures](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures)