# Changing 'Future<bool>' into static type 'bool' for condition

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

This question really, really similar like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691370/flutter-returning-a-bool-type-from-a-futurebool-method). I have followed the accepted answer but nothing happen.

I try to modify my first landing page on `main.dart` whether it's `HomePage()` or `OnBoardingPage()`. I'm getting data (bool) from Shared Preferences and do the checking first.

As you can see, the `OnBoardingPage()` is just a one-time-event screen.

Here the code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  SharedPrefs prefs = SharedPrefs();

  Future<bool> _initBro() async {
    var redirect = await prefs.read("onboard") ?? false;
    print("main => $redirect");
    return redirect;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'CM Sans Serif',
        platform: TargetPlatform.android,
      ),
      home: (_initBro().then(val => val == true)) ? HomePage() : OnBoardingPage(),
      // home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is on the `home:` line.

[image: main.dart]

I don't quite understand why it still giving me such error.
I have changed the code with await but, seems its giving me much more trouble. Also I have modified it a bit like this:

```
home: _initBro().then((val) {
  return (val) ? HomePage() : OnBoardingPage();
}),
```

But still no hope.

I'm new with Flutter and absolutely also with Dart. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you very much for paying attention guys.

Comment: why don't you call _initBro in main before check bool value in home

Comment: Try using `Futurebuilder`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FutureBuilder`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  SharedPrefs prefs = SharedPrefs();

  Future<bool> _initBro() async {
    var redirect = await prefs.read("onboard") ?? false;
    print("main => $redirect");
    return redirect;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'CM Sans Serif',
        platform: TargetPlatform.android,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder(builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData)
          return snapshot.data ? HomePage() : OnBoardingPage();
        else
          return Container();
      },
      future: _initBro(),);
    }
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

It returns widget synchronously. If there is no data yet - it returns empty `Container`, and when `_initBro()` returns value - this method will return needed widget

Comment: Thanks for your response, Andrey.
Actually, using `FutureBuilder` have comes up in my mind, but I'm just not sure will it work nor how to use it. Thanks for the code sample. Let me try it.