# Flutter and Future<bool> can't compare with bool value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426165/changing-futurebool-into-static-type-bool-for-condition) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691370/flutter-returning-a-bool-type-from-a-futurebool-method) questions that has a similar problem but none of the answers works for me and can't figured out why.

I need to check if in y SharedPreferences there is a bool value that should set the `initialRoute` value.

here the code:

```
import 'package:consegne_cernusco/pages/consegna-gratuita.dart';
import 'package:consegne_cernusco/pages/onboarding.dart';
import 'package:consegne_cernusco/pages/single_shop.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:consegne_cernusco/pages/shop_list.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import './pages/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // Future<bool> _shoudShowOnboardingPage;

  Future<bool> _shoudShowOnboardingPage() async {
    return _prefs.then((SharedPreferences p) {
      // p.remove('shoudShowOnboardingPage');
      return p.getBool('shoudShowOnboardingPage') ?? true;
    });
  }

  String showMainPage() {
    if (_shoudShowOnboardingPage().then((value) => value == true) == true) {
      return OnBoarding.routeName;
    }

    return HomePage.routeName;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Consegne Cernusco',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF009EE4),
        accentColor: Color(0xFF009FE3),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFF3F5F7),
      ),
      initialRoute: showMainPage(),
      routes: {
        HomePage.routeName: (ctx) => HomePage(),
        ShopListPage.routeName: (ctx) => ShopListPage(),
        SingleShopPage.routeName: (ctx) => SingleShopPage(),
        ConsegnaGratuita.routeName: (ctx) => ConsegnaGratuita(),
        OnBoarding.routeName: (ctx) => OnBoarding()
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that this line:

```
  if (_shoudShowOnboardingPage().then((value) => value == true) == true)
```

always returns `false` but can't understand how to manage it.

Any advice?

Comment: `main() => SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((p) => p.getBool('shoudShowOnboardingPage')).then((b) => runApp(MyApp(b)))`

Comment: and of course you have to add `MyApp` constructor with a `bool` parameter

Comment: I have tried your solution but no luck: `flutterError (ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before runApp() has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() first.`

Comment: you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.

Comment: so: `main() { WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((p) => p.getBool('shoudShowOnboardingPage')).then((b) => runApp(MyApp(b))); }` should work

Comment: Seems working as expected! Thanks! If you add your answer I'll be happy to mark it

Comment: great, write a self answer then ;-) btw you can also make `main() async {...` and use two `await` instead of cascade of `then()`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I solved thanks to @pskink comments.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences.getInstance()
      .then((p) => p.getBool('shoudShowOnboardingPage') ?? true)
      .then(
        (b) => runApp(
          MyApp(
            shouldSee: b,
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Because of the new param passed in `MyApp` I have change the class:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool shouldSee;
  MyApp({Key key, this.shouldSee});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
```

Now to access `shouldSee` just use `widget.shouldSee`:

```
initialRoute: widget.shouldSee == true ? OnBoarding.routeName : HomePage.routeName,
```

Comment: btw to make it more concise you cound use two `await`s instead of cascade of `then()`s